# Вывод чисел Каталана

Tags: java, математика

Вопрос про вывод чисел Каталана.
Код написан для решения вот этой задачи [Правильная скобочная последовательность](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C)

там же есть и мат часть. Работает неверно, так как при вводе числа 7 и более выдаёт совершенно не ожидаемый результат.
Вот мой код на Java написан, как по мне верно, не могу понять в чём подвох.

```
public class First_task {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter the number of brackets:");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int count_brackets = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println(bracket_sequence(count_brackets));
}

private static long bracket_sequence(int count_brackets) {
    return fact(2*count_brackets)/(fact(count_brackets)*fact(count_brackets+1));
}
private static int fact(int num) {
    return (num == 1) ? 1 : num * fact(num - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно, проблема в типе данных. При вводе 7 в формуле уже происходят огромные вычисления (в числителе (2*7)! ). Попробуй изменить тип int на long.

Comment: изменив int на long в fact() программа работает корректно)